# Kendo grid Headers always have a prefix "Column Setting" on every column when print

Tags: printing, kendo-ui, header, grid

When I print a kendo grid, it always put "Column Settings" string in front of every column header. Some settings are wrong? I don't have these before. Is it from some updates? Anyone has this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: *"Some settings are wrong?"* How should we know since you didn't shared it with us?

Comment: I finally figured out the link <link href="kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> point to the wrong position. But why it has no problem before?